# How can there be two different answers from two identical equations for the same value of $x$? $(x-1)/(x^2-1)$ and $1/(x+1)$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits

Given the following equation:

$$f(x) = \frac{x-1}{x^2-1}$$

find the limit of $f(x)$ when $x \to 1$.

I know how to solve it, by simplifying the above equation to $f(x)=1/(x+1)$, giving the answer $1/2$.

But my question is: $(x-1)/(x^2-1)$ is identical to $1/x+1$. How come $(x-1)/(x^2-1)$ gives $0/0$ when $x=1$, but $1/(x+1)$ gives $1/2$ when $x=1$?

Comment: They are not identical, one is undefined at $1$ and the other is not.

Comment: Would the person who saw fit to downvote this question be brave enough to tell why?

Comment: @PaulSinclair, I downvoted. All 3 questions from OP initially contain no capitalization or punctuation and require thorough editing from people who are nicer than I am. I believe a minimal amount of effort should be put into writing a readily readable question when you come to the community for help. Apparently I am in the minority.

Comment: @Ian, while your complaint is reasonable (and one with which I agree), you should in general give the user a comment explaining the reason. Otherwise you are just being rude, as the poster can't tell what to do next time to improve.

Comment: @PaulSinclair And yet the gods of Stack Exchange in there infinite wisdom have made voting anonymous. What is the point of anonymous voting if the vote must be explained with a nymous comment?

Comment: There should be a standard phrase  as a plea or request..  DVPJ ( DownVoterPleaseJustify!) which will DV(Latin)  be answered. Higher K reps  may hardly care. But newbies, it strikes them hard, specially  when they are trying hard to learn.

Comment: @bof, and what is the point of downvoting without a comment? It does no good at all for changing behavior. It is just bullying as far as I can see.

Answer (score 4):

The graphs for $f(x)=(x-1)/(x^2-1)$ and $g(x)=1/(x+1)$ are not equal: they differ for exactly one value of $x$, namely the one you gave! Specifically, $f$'s graph is just that of $g$, but with a "hole" punctured in it at the point $(1, 1/2)$. It's a [removable discontinuity](http://www.mathwords.com/r/removable_discontinuity.htm), like this one:

[image]

The reason this happens is that **$f(x)$ is just $g(x)$ multiplied by $(x-1)/(x-1)$**. We can examine the behaviour of that function more closely:

- If $x \neq 1$, then $(x-1)/(x-1)$ equals 1.
- If $x = 1$, it is $0/0$, which is undefined. (It's an [indeterminate form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form#Indeterminate_form_0.2F).)

So for all values of $x$ *but* one, we multiply by $1$, and the value of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ is equal. Only for $x=1$ our new function gets a "hole" added to it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses .well i understand what you are telling.  what i cant wrap my head around is (May the Math is beyond the level of what i can comprehend) how can these two equations not be identical.To put simply does this mean that when one function is manipulated algebraically in to a another form, that those two are not guaranteed to be identical?

Comment: The problem is that the algebraic manipulation you're performing is not entirely correct. By removing the factor $(x-1)/(x-1)$, you are **changing** how the function behaves at $x=1$, and it's no longer identical to where you started from.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Again your answer makes sense. But sorry if i sound stupid but when you say  "the algebraic manipulation you're performing is not entirely correct" Im thinking how can for some functions following algebraic rules result in manipulations that are correct and for some functions result in   manipulations that are not entirely correct (Again sorry if this sounds dumb, may be im thinking too much and getting my self confused)

Comment: Sorry for my late reply! Yes, it depends on the manipulation. You're thinking: "If I divide both the top and bottom parts of the fraction by the same thing ($x-1$), I'll get an equal function." But that isn't *always* true: namely, it fails in the case of $0/0$. (For comparison: if it had been some term that is never zero instead, like $x^2+1$, it would've been valid!)

Comment: Ok cool.i think i got it now.So to summarize if i say  that if a function f(x) is manipulated to a different form  g(x) using algebraic rules we cannot say that f(x)=g(x) for all values of x (unless we prove otherwise)

Comment: That sounds essentially right. Whenever you do a step of algebraic manipulation you need to think about: "am I dividing by zero, taking the square root of a negative number etc...?" and make sure you handle those cases appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

There are no two answers! As it is, the function is not well defined for x=1, as division by 0 is not defined. That is, you can't just substitute x=1 in the original expression. It makes sense only as a limit. Else, once you identify it with 1/x+1 you can ascribe it a finite value at x=1.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that the simplification $$\frac{x-1}{x^2-1}=\frac{1}{x+1}$$
is true iff $x^2-1\neq 0$ since this kind of manipulation is due to the properties of the real numbers and the quotient is not defined for $x^2-1=0$.

Comment: To put simply does this mean that generally when we change the form of a function f(x) by algebraic manipulation, the two functions are not guaranteed to be equal to all values of x

Answer (score 0):

What you have in the first case is a limit of a quotient with **an indefinite form**.

That is $\lim\limits_{x\to c} \dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}$, where $\lim\limits_{x\to c} f(x)=0$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to c} g(x)=0$.

Specifically you have $f(x)=x-1, g(x) = x^2-1$.   Both vanish at the limit point, $x=0$.

Such limits *can* be assigned a definite value using various techniques.   One such method is to cancel common terms which do not equal zero *near* the limit point.   (This term may equal zero *at* the limit point, as long as it does not do so on the approach.)

The term you cancelled was $(x-1)$.

---

So although $\frac{x-1}{x^2-1}$ and $\frac{1}{x+1}$ are only equal everywhere *but* at the point $x=1$, where the first function is discontinuous, both do approach the same limit there.

Answer (score 0):

They are two different functions, but they differ only in their domains -- what ***x*** is allowed to be. And the forbidden value is ***x*** **= 1**.

You are, however, allowed to as closely with this forbidden fruit as you like. The closer you get to ***x*** **= 1** in your initial equation, the closer you'll get to the value you're looking for.

Suppose you had a roadway with a gorge in its path. You can't travel the road to the other side because of the gorge. But you **can** build a bridge. That's what factoring did for you. The functions both go to the exact same place **except** where the gorge is.

Answer (score 0):

"But my question is: $(x−1)/(x^2−1)$ is identical to 1/x+1. How come $(x−1)/(x^2−1)$ gives 0/0 when x=1, but 1/(x+1) gives 1/2 when x=1?"

They are not identical. As others have noted, they are equal for all values except for x = 1, where they differ.

Recall that you can never divide by zero. When reducing rational expressions in the way that you're doing here, you technically have to keep track of any values that would have caused you to divide by zero, because they're not in the domain of the original expression. This is a detail that is glossed over in many classes or testing contexts, but is very important to avoid confusion in exactly this way. In your particular case, cancelling the $(x - 1)$ factor in the numerator & denominator does not hold if $x = 1$, because that would be division by zero. Thus:

$(x-1)/(x^2-1) = 1/(x+1)$ for all values of $x$ is a false statement.

$(x-1)/(x^2-1) = 1/(x+1)$ for all values $x ≠ 1$  is a true statement.

Comment: thanks for the explanation.But my problem then is that we simplify or change form of an algebraic expressions all the time in mathematics to find solutions to a given problem.How can we do that if the original function and simplification is not guaranteed to be identical

Comment: Like I said, you need to keep track of the domain (specifically, values that cause division by zero) and include that as part of your statements. It's what makes "(x−1)/(x^2−1)=1/(x+1)" false in general, but "(x−1)/(x^2−1)=1/(x+1) for all x ≠ 1" true.

Comment: Consider practicing this skill here: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra2/rational-expressions/simplifying-rational-alg/e/simplifying_rational_expressions_4

Comment: The attached video to the link above is fairly helpful, especially from time 2:25 to the end. Also consider practicing the specific skill of identifying the domain of a function here: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra2/functions-and-graphs/domain_range/e/domain_of_a_function